# Background image not stretching to full length of site (rails + bootstrap)

Tags: html, css

I'm using the exact same CSS on 2 pages. On both pages, I'd like the `background-image` to stretch to the full length/ width of the page. But this only works on 1 of the 2 pages.

This is a screenshot of the page that works (view it here: https://hidden-tundra-8656.herokuapp.com/geared?id=1
[image])

This is a screenshot of the page that doesn't work (view it here: https://hidden-tundra-8656.herokuapp.com/membership?referer_invite_code=f187b2)
[image]

In both pages, all the contents are wrapped in the following basic layout:

```
<div class="container-fluid zero-padding success-container">
  <div class="row-fluid text-center zero-margin">
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 center-box">
      <!-- page content -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS code for success-container**

```
html {
  height: 100%; 
}
body {
  height: 100%;
}
.success-container {
  background-position: center; 
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  padding-left:0;
  padding-right:0;
  padding-bottom:0;
  padding-top:0;
  margin-top:0;
  margin-bottom:0;
  margin-left:0;
  margin-right:0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: cloudinary-url("jumbotron_camping.jpg", $width: 1000,$crop: "fill", $gravity: "north", $type:"upload")
}

.center-box {
  background-color: white;
  margin-top:10%;
  border: $gray solid 1px;
  padding-top:5%;
  padding-bottom:2%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the HTML in both pages you'll see that the CSS is working fine. However, in your second page the Form displayed is actually longer than the height of the screen. For some reason, it's embedded in a way that it doesn't make your `<body>` element scroll (you using iframes or something?).

Comment: I'm not... that's weird, what else might cause that?

Comment: Did you change something? Seems to be working fine now!

Comment: yes someone here had an answer that's gone, I just had to remove `height:100%` from `center-box`, which btw I don't undersatnd why... plus your answer seems to be more addressing a root issue

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11095288)

Comment: @Ian this does provide an attempt to answer the question, it definitely isn't a good answer, but it should not have been flagged, and should not be recommended for deletion in the LQPRQ. If users who have the vote to delete answers privilege think that this should be deleted, it is up to them to case delete votes. Flags are not a substitute for delete votes, and neither is the LQPRQ. Please see: [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue)